# Why are apps disappearing after I install them?

Tags: unity, compiz

I am new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general). I installed Ubuntu 13.04 (after many installs of 12.04 and failed Office installs even though the web swears it's possible). I gave up on getting Office installed.

Anyway, yesterday all of a sudden I noticed **Ubuntu Software Center** was gone. So I rebooted. Then, upon logging in, I had a blank desktop. Thankfully I left Windows 7 installed on a separate partition so I logged in and Googled it. I ended up finding some info about booting up, invoking terminal -- but wait, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> didn't work anymore either! :(

Booted Windows 7 back up and Googled THAT. Found info about `ccsm` and also `unity --reset`. I booted back into Ubuntu, managed to get to a terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I typed `ccsm` and it said that wasn't installed.

Back to Windows 7. Google. Found info about resetting Unity by doing `unity --reset`. Then read that was deprecated and to use `replace`. Then read that was deprecated too. AHHHH! I decided to just boot Ubuntu and try things people said WEREN'T possible, because I had the notion that anything I read that WAS possible wasn't, and vise versa.

Booted into Ubuntu, ran `unity --reset` and it told me Unity wasn't installed. Thankfully, it said: to install just type `sudo apt-get install unity`. That worked, and, upon reboot and logging in I now have my desktop icons -- or should I say that left panel thingy. Ubuntu Software Center was still gone but I was able to install that via another command...even though I used to have it already.

Finally, to my question. How does stuff just disappear? Did my Ubuntu install somehow roll back? I don't remember uninstalling anything to make a lot of built-in things just disappear. I installed Guake (the transparent terminal) and now that's gone too. When I install stuff, is it installing it to a certain shell? Session? When I press the "Super Key" (the Windows logo key) and type `term`, I no longer have the built-in terminal app. Huh?! But, I have UXTerm and XTerm -- both apps I never saw before when I searched for "term" in the search...thingy.

Ideas? Insight? Anything would be helpful at this point. I LOVE Ubuntu and I'm glad I installed it. NOT going back to Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: When talking about invoking terminal, I meant CTRL+ALT+T, not CTRL+ALT+DEL... I'd edit my post but can't figure out how.

Comment: Try installing `ubuntu-desktop` with this command: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. It sounds like you're missing a lot of programs provided by this package

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Dan! I've edited your question for you. However, you can [edit] it by clicking on the `edit` link right underneath the text of your question. Thanks!

Comment: Please use the service http://paste.ubuntu.com to upload the file `/var/log/apt/history.log`. What you describe looks like a result of a not-recommended software installation gone wrong and I'd like to see what actually has been done. Also, please describe how you have installed 13.04: from scratch, formatting the hard disk, or in some other way?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6107998/ -- Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, it looks like "compiz" is what went wrong and installing unity brought my panel back, but not the apps.